# Drag and Drop between two RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Is it possible to have feature like drag and drop between two different `RecyclerView`?

I found [library](https://github.com/vinc3m1/DragSortAdapter) for drag and drop within `RecyclerView`. Please help me to improve this functionality.

Comment: Did you got any solution for your problem? I also need the same.

Comment: sorry i moved to some other work

Comment: Would be awesome if someone puts an answer to this..

Comment: Is anyone found solution of this problem, I m also trying to move item between 2 different RecyclerView. @bumba

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar requirement in one of our projects. You can check out the sample code that I have uploaded here - [RecyclerView Drag and Drop](https://github.com/pooja-gaikwad15/recyclerview-list-drag-and-drop)

It is a very basic code that matches your requirement
- Drag and drop within a single recyclerview as well as between two different recyclerviews.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is working fine without any ItemAnimation.

Comment: @ramji did you find any solution with adding ItemAnimation ?

Comment: how will you manage if no data available in second list. this is working only when items available in both list.

Answer (score 19):

Check out my [code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/jkozh/DragDropTwoRecyclerViews). It will help you understand how to `Drag and Drop` between two `RecyclerView`s.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, gives gradle errors. Rip

Comment: @Shazniq The example does work. It requires small modifications and then it runs just fine.

Comment: please, Could you update the project or show some steps to run successfully in 2022?

Answer (score 6):

No need to  use third party  library's,Support library now supporting  the   drag and  drop  of recyleview, may  be this article will  help  you

https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd

Answer (score 3):

This [lib](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) can help you. 
Check sample example, it does what you asked.
It has a BoardView, where you can put several lists.

YouTube demo-video: https://youtu.be/tNgevYpyA9E?t=30

> Features
>
> - Re-order items in a list, grid or board by dragging and dropping with    nice animations.
> - Add custom animations when the drag is starting and ending.
> - Get a callback when a drag is started and ended with the position.
> - Disable and enable drag and drop

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i am looking for