# drag and drop between two recyclerview (again)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, android-5.0-lollipop

Is it even possible to drag and drop Recyclerview ? It looks like it's not a problem inside of a Recyclerview, but I can't make item go outside of it. Like every drag and drop that I've seen, this operation works only inside of a container(recyclerview in this case). So is it even possible to do that or it's just a huge time waste from me?
on **sof** already was question like that [overhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690522/drag-and-drop-between-two-recyclerview), but it was not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to drag and drop between 2 different RecyclerViews. Someone tried to solve that problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469713/drag-and-drop-between-two-recycle-view) and ended up creating a GitHub lib.