# Drag and Drop Between Two Recycle View

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I have created 2 Horizontal recycleView. Which is working perfectly. I need the functionality of drag and drop between item inside each recycleView as well as drag and drop between those two recycleView's item. What I did still now -

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewCompletedTask;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapterCompletedTask;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManagerCompletedTask;
private static String LOG_TAG = "RecyclerViewActivity";
private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewInCompleteTask;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapterInCompleteTask;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManagerInCompleteTask;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    mRecyclerViewCompletedTask = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_completed_task);
    mRecyclerViewCompletedTask.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManagerCompletedTask = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerViewCompletedTask.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerCompletedTask);
    mAdapterCompletedTask = new MyRecyclerViewAdapterCompletedTask(getDataSet());
    mRecyclerViewCompletedTask.setAdapter(mAdapterCompletedTask);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerViewCompletedTask.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);

    mRecyclerViewInCompleteTask = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_incomplete_task);
    mRecyclerViewInCompleteTask.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManagerInCompleteTask = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerViewInCompleteTask.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerInCompleteTask);
    mAdapterInCompleteTask = new MyRecyclerViewAdapterInCompleteTask(getDataSet());
    mRecyclerViewInCompleteTask.setAdapter(mAdapterInCompleteTask);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerViewInCompleteTask.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MyRecyclerViewAdapterCompletedTask) mAdapterCompletedTask).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapterCompletedTask.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);
        }
    });
    ((MyRecyclerViewAdapterInCompleteTask) mAdapterInCompleteTask).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapterInCompleteTask.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<DataObject> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
    for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
        DataObject obj = new DataObject("Some Primary Text " + index,
                "Secondary " + index);
        results.add(index, obj);
    }
    return results;
}
```

**Customised this library and got the things that I want. Link - https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView**

Comment: Updated my question.
If you like it upvote me

Comment: Can you describe what you changed within the library?

Comment: added in ans Upvote please

Answer (score 9):

If you are still interested in a simple solution [see my code on GitHub](https://github.com/jkozh/DragDropTwoRecyclerViews). It's shows how to `Drag and Drop` between two `RecyclerView`s.

[image]

Comment: This solution is almost perfect. I would only suggest changing the `View.OnDragListener` to a `View.OnLongClickListener`. This allows (1) the RecyclerView to scroll and (2) to drag onto the RecyclerView even if its visible window is full.

Comment: How to do this with OnLongClickListener?

Comment: @LakshyaPunhani , @JuliaKo and @jshapy How will we get to to know that we have dropped the item from `RecyclerView1` to another or vice versa ?

Comment: Looks good. Can I reorder/drug items inside single list?

Answer (score 1):

Customised this library and got the things that I want. Link - https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView

**What I updated -**

As you can see it's a vertical recyclerView use layout manager so that you can make it Gird or Horizontal recylerView. In my case I have 2 recyclerView and 1 GridView. Also adjusted some padding and layout.