# Drag and drop in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, gridlayoutmanager

I have ViewPager. On every page I have RecycleView (various instances) with GridLayoutManager. How can I drag and drop items (from RecycleView) between pages? I found View.startDrag() function, but it loses all move animations provided by RecycleView.

I want to achieve [it](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbKqENKCio0)) but with ViewPager instead of HorizontalScrollView.

Thank you for help,
Patryk

Comment: https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3317

Comment: this is the same lib as in video check it https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4036

Comment: you can check here, https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView

Comment: link to sources to app from video is under "it" word :)

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you for links but I can't find functionality, which I am looking for. I want to drag item from one  RecycleView to other RecycleView.

Comment: @patrykcd check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690522/drag-and-drop-between-two-recyclerview

Comment: @patrykcd check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469713/drag-and-drop-between-two-recycle-view

Comment: it seems that it is impossible with ViewPager. I must switch to HorizontalScrollView :(