# How to handle objects between recyclerviews?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I am fairly new to android developing and my problem is that I want to drag a object out of a list of objects from one RecyclerView to an other one (that triggers a event afterwards but step by step for now).

I managed to set up a adapter for the class I implemented and the objects are in my RecyclerView just as I wanted them to be. I know that I have to implement an OnTouchListener with the onDrag- and the onTouch- methods for the drag and drop feature but there are only a few examples and none of them I looked up so far are for containers like ArrayList.

Can somebody please show me some example code or a link to a guide how to implement this in a proper way?

Thank you very much for your effort in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate. Searching for "drag drop recyclerview" here on stackoverflow gives a lot of results. See for example [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469713/drag-and-drop-between-two-recycle-view)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!